# Cloud9 & Meteor.js undefined global var

Tags: mongodb, meteor, undefined, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to create the Leaderboard on Cloud9. But I get the error: PlayersList not defined... in the editor. The app is working, but then it's code in editor underlining all 'not defind PlayersList'

The code:

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

if(Meteor.isClient){

   Template.leaderboard.helpers({

      'player': function(){
        return PlayersList.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
    },

    'selectedClass': function(){
      var playerId = this._id;
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      if(selectedPlayer === playerId){
      return 'selected';
      }
    },

    'showSelectedPlayer': function(){
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      return PlayersList.findOne(selectedPlayer);
    }

   });
```

Comment: When putting it like this:  var PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');   ....all is ok...

Comment: is the problem with the editor only, or does meteor complain too?

Comment: When I use: var PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');  the app won't work...but errors in editor are gone...when using: PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');  app works fine, but editor error-underlines the var (PlayersList)

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9's editor uses [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint), and using `foo = 22` makes it think that there's a missing statement like `var foo;` somewhere. You can either choose to ignore this, or fix it as follows:

Add `/*eslint-env meteor */` to the top so it doesn't give warnings about Meteor  globals, and maybe you'll also need to add `/* globals Player */` added too in case the error still stays. (I haven't tested this out, please let me know how it goes so I can improve the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a little workaround. I added coffeescript and then I used the `@` symbol on the global like you should, when you define a collection with coffeescript. And that was solving it for me. It works fine. As I opened the app in an new browser window, posts were available in the console.

Example:

```
@Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts')
```

Comment: Yes, that's a little dirty trick. You see, Meteor does its own namespacing (file and package scope; see: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/namespacing); however this does not work with CoffeeScript because it does not declare variables with `var`.